# Difference in ways of returning from function

Tags: javascript, function, return

Is there a difference in these two ways of returning from a function?

```js
const failed = true;

const checkFailA = () => {
  if (failed) return console.log("failed");
}

const checkFailB = () => {
  if (failed) {
    console.log("failed");
    return;
  }
}

checkFailA();
checkFailB();
```

As far as I understand, in the first function, `console.log()` gets returned causing the function to `return` and log the message. In the second function, `console.log()` is called before returning, also causing the function to log the message and `return`.

Would it make a difference in this server code example? I was following a tutorial where the person used both methods alternately and got confused.

```js
// server

// A
if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: err });

// B
if (err) {
  res.status(500).send({ message: err });
  return;
}
```

Comment: Your example and the tutorial are very much different.

Comment: @Yousaf thank you for pointing that out, if you don't use the return value, could you use method `A`?

Comment: Well `console.log()` returns `undefined`, as does a plain `return` statement, so yes in A both examples are equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I understand, in the first function, console.log() gets
> returned

No. It returns the *result* of calling `console.log(...)`, i.e. `undefined`.

In the following code example, `return` statement will return whatever the expression in-front of it evaluates to.

In this case, because of the comma operator, `(console.log("failed"), 1)` evaluates to `1` and that is what's gets returned from the function.

But `console.log` is still called, so `"failed"` also gets logged on the console.

```js
const failed = true;

const checkFailA = () => {
  if (failed) return (console.log("failed"), 1);
}

console.log(checkFailA());
```

In the second code example, function returns `undefined` because there is no expression `after` the `return` keyword.

> Would it make a difference in this server code example?

It won't make a difference because `res.status(...).send(...)` doesn't returns anything. Even if it did, it won't matter because its return value is not used anywhere.

Having said that, i would personally prefer using (method b) because that's more readable in my opinion.

Comment: I like method `A` because it only takes one line but method `B` is more readable so I guess I'll stick with that.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in that first example the FUNCTION is returning the console.log()

In the second example, the function is returning void but the console.log is still being printed because it was in the function body.

For the server-side it usually makes difference while you are returning something that is not a promise then you can chain it with another .then() block

like this

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000); // (*)

}).then(function(result) { // (**)

  alert(result); // 1
  return result * 2;

}).then(function(result) { // (***)

  alert(result); // 2
  return result * 2;

}).then(function(result) {

  alert(result); // 4
  return result * 2;

});
```

Comment: I understand that `B` returns nothing and `A` does, but if you don't use the return value, could you use method `A`?

Comment: It depends...for the console.log() maybe it's the same but if your function is a CALLBACK function and you want to return that value to the function that is calling it, then you have to return that value...

Comment: If you do not use the return value, than do not return anything, just omit it.